# flutter, dart : How convert formatted DateTime to its original form

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, flutter-intl

_date = DateFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy').format(_rawDateTime);

I have formatted the above **_date** with **Intl package** for displaying and now I have to send back to server and server require original format so how I can convert the above formatted date back into its original format.
the server required format is **2022-08-19T09:12:15.406Z**

Comment: What kind of server?  It's possible you'll want to avoid any string phase and do it as number-to-number transfers.  True of things like Firebase and others.

Comment: Why convert the `DateTime` to a `String` just to convert it back to a `DateTime` later?  You should convert the `DateTime` to a `String` *only* when you need to display it.  You should be storing the `DateTime`, not its `String` representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You track  `DateFormat` and use `.parse` on string.

```dart
final formatter = DateFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy');
final _date = formatter.format(_rawDateTime);
final data = formatter.parse(_date);
```

For utc

```dart
final data = formatter.parse(_date).toUtc(); //2022-08-19 18:00:00.000Z
```

Only date will be available from this because the formatter already parsed only date part here.

Comment: Glad to help, you can check more about [DateFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.htm)